# Built-in Swipe Gesture in onDelete function of a List that is inside a TabView not working

Tags: list, swiftui, scrollview, gesture, tabview

I have a TabView with only to items, the TabView style is **.page(indexDisplayMode: .never)** so you can switch views using the swipe gesture. As expected no Bar is shown at the bottom:

```
enum TabItems {
    case home
    case statistics
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedTab: TabItems = .home

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            Home()
            Statistics()
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
    }
}
```

Home and Statictics views contains a list of numbers. You should be able to delete any number by swiping the row from the left to the right as usual:

```
struct Home: View {
    @State var numbers: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(numbers, id: \.self) { number in
                    Text("Number: \(number)")
                }
                .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                    numbers.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Statistics: View {
    @State var numbers: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(numbers, id: \.self) { number in
                    Text("\(number)")
                }
                .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                    numbers.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem**:
The swiping gesture of the TabView conflicts with the swiping gesture when trying to delete a number from the List. It makes almost impossible to delete a number.

[image]

*"Is there a way to address this conflict by prioritizing the built-in List's swipe gesture on deletion?"*

**PD**
Please read carefully, there are some issues posted quite similar to this, but they do not address this use case. The hierarchy of the components and their behaviours must remain. You should be able to reproduce it using the code above. Thanks in advance

Code run on Version 14.3.1, simulator iphone 14 Pro, iOS 16.4

Comment: Yeah I also had the same issue with deleting in a list inside a tabview, it would not recognise the delete swipe so I ended up replacing the default delete function with a contextMenu button instead.

Comment: In this situation, you will always have a conflict in the gestures. If you use a paged TabView, you can't use horizontal swipe gestures inside like this.